# Como excluir um item de um array pelo valor do atributo?

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte *array* com alguns itens:

```
var arr = [
    {id: 1, name: "Jon Snow"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "Michael Scolfield"}, 
    {id: 3, name: "Dexter Morgan"}
];
```

Para adicionar novo item é usado o método `push`. Exatamente desta forma:

```
arr.push({
  id: 1,
  name: "Jon Snow"
})
```

Percebi que é possível remover usando o método `splice()` passando o índice como parâmetro. Veja:

```
arr.splice(index,1);
```

Porém preciso excluir um item do *array* passando como parâmetro o *`id`*, que seria um atributo do objeto. Exemplo:

```
function removeItem(id){
    //remover o objecto com id específico
}
```

Como excluir um item de um *array* passando como parâmetro seu `id`? Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Precisa encontrar o elemento usando o método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example), depois é só capturar o índice do elemento usando [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) e removê-lo.

Também é possível criar um novo *array* apenas com os elementos que não correspondem ao seu critério de exclusão. Perceba que nesta abordagem o *array* original **não é alterado**.

```js
var arr = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Duplicado'}, 
    {id: 1, name: 'John Snow'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'Michael Scolfield'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'Dexter Morgan'}
];

removerPorId(arr, 1);
arr = removerPorId2(arr, 2);

console.log(arr);

// Opção 1
function removerPorId(array, id) {
  var result = array.filter(function(el) {
    return el.id == id;
  });
    
  for(var elemento of result){
    var index = array.indexOf(elemento);    
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

// Opção 2
function removerPorId2(array, id) {
  return array.filter(function(el) { 
    return el.id !== id; 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Utilize [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example).

```
function removeItem(arr, refId) {
    return arr.filter(function(i) { return i.id !== refId; });
};
```

Comment: Acho que tem um erro aqui, não funfou! ^^

Comment: @acklay Oops! tente de novo, esqueci de remover um trecho ao renomear.=)

Answer (score 3):

Aconselho a utilizar a lib [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) para manipular Java Script. Essa lib compactada com apenas o core tem 4kb. Possui diversas funcionalidades para manipular itens em javascript, sempre a utilizo em meus projetos, recomendo. ;)

Com ele seria simples assim:

```js
var arr = [
    {id: 1, name: 'John Snow'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Michael Scolfield'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'Dexter Morgan'}
];

// Objeto com o Dexter
console.log(arr);

// Remove Dexter
arr.splice(_.findIndex(arr, {id: 3}), 1);

// Objeto sem o Dexter
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Há duas maneiras fazer isso:

- criando uma nova array com um elemento a menos
- mudando a array atual

### criando uma nova array com um elemento a menos

Já há respostas que referem alguns métodos, mas o mais rápido é usando um loop `for`.
([teste no jsPerf aqui](https://jsperf.com/array-loop-vs-filter))

```js
function filtrar(arr, id) {
  var res = []
  for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i !== j; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id !== id) res.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return res;
};

var arr = [
    {id: 1, name: 'John Snow'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'Michael Scolfield'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'Dexter Morgan'}
];

console.log(filtrar(arr, 1));
```

### mudando a array atual

```js
function filtrar(arr, id) {

  for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i !== j; i++) {
    if (arr[i].id === id) break;
  }
  arr.splice(i, 1);
};

var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Snow'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Michael Scolfield'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Dexter Morgan'
  }
];

filtrar(arr, 1);
console.log(arr);
```